# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: Failed to parse APK file:

Tags: android, migration, apk, androidx

I have search stockoverflow and google with no luck. I recently migrated my app  to androidx, after a lot of effort I was able to fix all the build fails. but now I am getting the following error when the app is installing on the emulator or the device. any help will be highly appreciated.

I have tried the following:
invalidate caches/restart
clean build and rebuild project
uninstalled app from the device
restarted my pc

```
Exception occurred while executing:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: Failed to parse APK file: /data/local/tmp/...
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:338)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:906)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:158)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21328)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:634)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:532)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:2821)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:3856)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse /data/local/tmp/...
    at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLiteInner(PackageParser.java:1590)
    at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parseApkLite(PackageParser.java:1575)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.setParamsSize(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:331)
    ... 9 more
$ adb shell pm uninstall ...
Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731))
Error while Installing APK
```

Comment: The output of logcat may possibly give some indication of the issue before the stacktrace.

Comment: Hi Pierre, thank you for your response, this is some of the logcat output when the error happens     2018-12-07 08:10:16.541 2049-5709/system_process W/ResourceType: Bad string block: last string is not 0-terminated
2018-12-07 08:10:16.541 2049-5709/system_process E/system_server: RES_STRING_POOL_TYPE corrupt.
2018-12-07 08:10:16.541 2049-5709/system_process E/system_server: Failed to load 'resources.arsc' in APK '/data/local/tmp/...

Comment: @Pierre These are the errors in the logcat 2018-12-07 09:14:03.134 1109-9002/? E/system_server: RES_STRING_POOL_TYPE corrupt.
2018-12-07 09:14:03.134 1109-9002/? E/system_server: Failed to load 'resources.arsc' in APK '/data/local/tmp/....
    
    --------- beginning of system
2018-12-07 09:14:06.288 31289-31289/? E/ogle.android.g: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2018-12-07 09:14:06.732 2900-31340/? E/ndroid.systemu: Invalid ID 0x00000000...

Comment: Looks like your build system is having an issue building a valid resource table. Are you using Gradle? If so, which version? If not, what are you using to build your APK?

Comment: @Pierre, thank you so much Pierre, I really appreciate your help since this issue is really hard for me to figure out. great question, I am using Gradle, I was actually able to install this with a Gradle version 3.1.4(original version when the app was built) but when I upgraded to Gradle 3.2.1 this is where it is falling. steps I took so far to try to resolve this: deleted the Gradle cache in user/.graddle/caches and unsintalled then re-installed android studio with no luck. i also un-migrated from androidx and it is working in gradle 3.1.4 but gives this error in gradle 3.2.1

Comment: I also unchecked instant run in the settings

Comment: Can you make sure aapt2 is not disabled in the Gradle properties?

Comment: @pierre, thank you for all your help Pierre, I actually was able to fix this issue. it was due to a old installation directory of android studio in the file system (3.1) after deleting that directory it works not.

Answer (score 11):

Delete the previous app-release.apk file from the android folder:

`\app\build\outputs\apk\release`

Then clear all data from the emulator. Finally, rebuild the application.

Answer (score 1):

Clean -> Rebuild -> and try to check both v1 and v2 while generating apk file

Comment: Thank you Uma for your response, I have tried this and also tried bulding a signed apk and installing it via adb with no luck.

Comment: just to note this as well, when I try to install through adb I get the following error Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NOT_APK: Failed to parse /data/app/vmdl1116562896.tmp/base.apk]

Answer (score 0):

You should drop the cache on your mobile.
for example:

1- open your windows terminal on your computer

2 - enter the command `>adb shell`
you should be insite on your mobile

3 - enter to the tmp/appium_cache/ folder with `>cd data/local/tmp/appium_cache`

4 - write the command `>ls` to see all the elements that there is insite of that folder

5 - drop all that elements with the command `>rm filename`

hope to help you

Answer (score 0):

just delete build folder and run again

android/app/build